# Is it grammatical to say "Here is very nice?"

Tags: american-english, grammaticality-in-context

[image]There is a question that comes across to me--the word 'here' is a noun as well an adverb.

Based on these two sentences:

***I like it here.***
***I like here.***
***Here is the book that you are looking for.***

The word 'here' in the first sentence is act as an adverb, whereas the word 'here' in the third sentence is a noun and a subject.I'm wondering why the second sentence is ungrammatical, as the word 'here' could also be a noun in the second sentence, which is "I like + **noun**, and **noun** is 'here'".In addition, is it suitable to say "Here is absolutely great"?

Hope there is someone is willing to resolve my doubt, please 〒_〒.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is very nice* is grammatical but not *usually* how a native speaker would make a comment that focuses on the niceness, which would be instead *It's very nice here*.

However, if you've been looking for a place, perhaps to put a picnic blanket down, or for a new apartment, and have tried several places, and wish to emphasize that the place you're at now is quite acceptable, then you could put "Here" at the beginning of the sentence as you have done, emphasizing the place *versus other places*:

> Here is very nice.

Similarly, if you wish to emphasize the place you are now in comparison to some other place or places, "I like *here*" is grammatical and idiomatic.

> We could sign a lease for the apartment in the city. That apartment was small but convenient. Shall we?
>
> -- Actually, **I like here** better. The commute will be longer but it's quieter, and there's a park nearby

So, the choice of phrasing (whether **here** can be subject or object) depends on whether your emphasis is on the place *per se*, or on a quality the place has. To focus on a quality or ambience the place has, you would say:

> I like it here.

Answer (score 1):

**Here** is *not* a noun. It is an adverb meaning 'in this place'. **Here is the book** is another way of saying **The book is here** (the adverb is placed first to emphasise that you are showing the book to the person who wants it).

We normally say **I like it here** and not *I like here* (**it** refers to the atmosphere of the place, or some quality of the place that pleases you). However in some informal contexts, like looking for a place to sit down, we might say something like **Here will do.**

Comment: No; in modern grammar "here" is not an adverb but an intransitive preposition. In, for example, "I like it here", it is interpreted deictically. Compare "I like it in this place", where the prepositional meaning becomes clear.

Comment: @BillJ - I bow to your superior knowledge. The dictionary I checked says it's an adverb!